# JSON path semantics different in kubectl and additional printer columns in custom resource definition

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath, kubernetes-custom-resources

I use `kubectl` to list Kubernetes custom resources of a kind `mykind` with an additional table column `LABEL` that contains the value of a label `a.b.c.com/key` if present:

```
kubectl get mykind -o=custom-columns=LABEL:.metadata.labels.'a\.b\.c\.com/key'
```

This works, i.e., the label value is properly displayed.

Subsequently, I wanted to add a corresponding additional printer column to the custom resource definition of `mykind`:

```
- description: Label value
  jsonPath: .metadata.labels.'a\.b\.c\.com/key'
  name: LABEL
  type: string
```

Although the additional column is added to `kubectl get mykind`, it is empty and no label value is shown (in contrast to above `kubectl` command). My only suspicion were problems with escaping of the special characters - but no variation helped.

Are you aware of any difference between the JSON path handling in `kubectl` and additional printer columns? I expected strongly that they are exactly the same.

Comment: Including those `'` characters is a shell concession, and are not part of jsonpath; you can change it in yaml to be `jsonPath: '.metadata.labels.a\.b\.c\.com/key'` and it will become legal yaml again, although I don't know that it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

mdaniel's comment works!

```yaml
- description: Label value
  jsonPath: '.metadata.labels.a\.b\.c\.com/key'
  name: LABEL
  type: string
```

You need to use `\.` instead of `.` and use single quotes `' '`. It doesn't work with double quotes for the reasons I don't understand